# AngularJS ng-pattern [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have a little problem with my regex in AngularJS

my regex in the html looks like this:

```
ng-pattern="[adfijmPrsyz\d]+"
```

but i get an error in the console which says:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 12-12 [\] in expression [[adfijmPrsyz\d]+].
```

my regex should achieve this: Only a, d, f, i, j, m, P, r, s, y, z and numbers 0 to 9 should be valid.

it would be nice if i could set the regex in the controller instead of hardcoding it in the html file.

like this:

`private regex: any = /[adfijmPrsyz\d+]/;`

`<input name="REFZEILE" ng-pattern="regex" />`

Comment: Try using a regex literal notation in ng-pattern with `[0-9]` to see if there is any difference - `ng-pattern="/^[adfijmPrsyz0-9]+$/"`. See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6h9rSEcvEQEWvRoMY1cd?p=preview) for an example of how the regex can be set in the controller (`$scope.regex = '[adfijmPrsyz\\d]+';`).

Comment: `ngPattern` expects a scope variable, not a string.

Comment: @zeroflagL `ngPattern` accepts both, but when using a string you have to enclose it in quotes just like any other time you are supplying a string to an Angular directive.

Comment: @Lex Let's put it this way: It expects an expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually define the regex in your controller - you just need to use `new RegExp()`. When using regex inline you have to tell Angular that it's a string by enclosing it in quotes (single in your case since you are using double quotes on the attribute value), otherwise Angular tries to evaluate it as a variable. Here is a working example that shows both methods in action.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.regex = new RegExp(/^[adfijmPrsyz\d]+$/);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="testForm">
    Using controller RegExp:
    <input type="text" name="testInput" ng-model="testInput" ng-pattern="regex" required>
    <div ng-messages="testForm.testInput.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">A value is required</div>
      <div ng-message="pattern">Value entered is not valid</div>
    </div>
    Using inline RegExp:
    <input type="text" name="testInput2" ng-model="testInput2" ng-pattern="'[adfijmPrsyz\d]+'" required>
    <div ng-messages="testForm.testInput2.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">A value is required</div>
      <div ng-message="pattern">Value entered is not valid</div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for `new RegExp()`. `/.../` already **is** a RegExp.